# Solving for the relationship between two regression coefficients

Tags: variance, data-transformation, regression-coefficients, covariance

Is it possible to write $\beta$ as a function of $\gamma$ given the following definitions:

$$\beta = \frac{cov(\log(W+X),\log(Y))}{var(\log(W+X))}$$
$$\gamma = \frac{cov(\log(W),\log(Y))}{var(\log(W))}$$

where $W$,$X$, and $Y$ are all random variables?

Comment: The short answer is no.  You can't even derive bounds for $\beta$ in terms of $\gamma:$ no matter what $\gamma$ is, $\beta$ could be anything.  If you think this should be possible, perhaps there are additional constraints in your application that would help.  What might they be?

Comment: Interesting, would it be useful if the non-log-transformed coefficients were equal? As in: $$\frac{cov((W+X),Y)}{var((W+X))} = \frac{cov(W,Y)}{var(W)}$$.

Comment: There's no necessary relationship between the coefficients and the coefficients of the logged model.  They can be *totally* different.  So, consider an extreme case in which $X$ is a constant (or, for all practical purposes, nearly so). The original coefficients are equal. However, the value of $\beta$ is incredibly sensitive to what that constant might be.  For it even to make sense, $W+X$ must be positive almost surely; so by taking $X$ with values near the negative lower bound of $W,$ $\log(W+X)$ can attain extremely large values, completely changing $\beta.$

Comment: Ok, well let's assume that both $X$ and $(W+X)$ are always non-negative. And then take your extreme case where $X=x$ is a known constant. If we know that a one unit change in $W$ corresponds to a $\gamma$ unit change in $Y$, doesn't that imply that, on average, a 1 log-point change in $(W+x)$ is equal to a $\log(\gamma)$ unit change in $\log(Y)$?

Comment: I just simulated the above relationship and it appears to hold per the following: assume $x=1$; $\beta=1$; $W$ is i.i.d. from a uniform distribution over (0,1). Then, define $\log(Y) = 1 + \beta*\log(W+x)$. Then, if you regress $Y$ on $W$ and a constant, you obtain a coefficient on $W$ ($\gamma$) of 2.718..., and  $\log(2.718...)$ equals 1=$\beta$. Therefore, in this case at least, $\beta=\log(\gamma)$.

Comment: Furthermore, I just performed many simulations where $X$ is not a constant, but is a random variable with uniform support over many different non-zero domains and, on average, find that $\beta=\log(\gamma)$.

Comment: Your simulations, then, are not fully general and must embody some assumptions you have not stated here.

Comment: @km5041 Please put your simulation code and results in the original post.